# Is a German driver’s license valid in Florida?

Tags: international-travel, driving, car-rentals, driving-licenses, miami

Morning everyone,
I have a German driver's license and am planning to do a trip to Miami for 2 weeks, I was looking online for car to rent and I've found this:

> General Rental Information
>
> Driver's License Requirements
>
> Driver's license printed with non Roman Alphabet (Arabic, Chinese,
> Japanese, Cyrillic etc) must be complemented by an international
> driver's license. For driver's licenses from countries not part of the
> international driver's license treaty, an official translation of the
> license must be presented with the original license.

so, is my German license valid to rent a car in Miami??

thanks

---

according to this:

https://www.flhsmv.gov/driver-licenses-id-cards/visiting-florida-faqs/

> Visiting from another country?
>
> Visitors to Florida who wish to drive while here are required to have
> in their immediate possession a valid driver license issued in his or
> her name from their country of residence.
>
> If renting a car while visiting Florida, we suggest you check with the
> rental car company prior to your visit to see what they require.
> However, it’s our understanding that rental car companies have not
> changed their procedures or requirements for having a valid driver
> license from any state, U.S. territory or foreign country.

Comment: don't forget they have speed limits there!  :)

Answer (score 5):

Anecdotally: German license is fine. I have both a German and an international license, and every rental place in every country & state (including Florida) only wanted to see the German one when being offered both. The international one is in my experience quite useless.

Caveat: I haven't done that recently in Florida since I have also a US license now, so I always use that in the US these days.

Comment: We have seen here that rental places do not always check for international licenses even when one is legally needed.

Comment: @Willeke: Do you have any information that indicates one is in fact needed? Beween the quotes from the OP (the first of which plainly doesn't concern German licenses) and the two sets of anecdotal evidence, I can see no such indication at all.

Comment: I just pointed out that personal experience with rental companies is not the same as an official site showing and IDP is or isn't needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, rental car companies in Florida are well aware how German drivers licenses look, and used to them (they see probably a hundred every day).

Getting an international drivers license for Florida is a waste of money, as they typically don't know them, and often reject them (they shouldn't - but the checkout clerk does not know them, and what can you do).

[source: I live in Florida, and regulary rent cars with visiting Germans]

Comment: Same comment as on the first answer, rental agencies do not always check for IDP even when legally needed.